# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in .Net Maui 7 Style

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I have self-developed control which has one property as below:

```
public TextAlignment HorizontalIconAlignment { get { return (TextAlignment)GetValue(HorizontalIconAlignmentProperty); } set { SetValue(HorizontalIconAlignmentProperty, value); } }
public static readonly BindableProperty HorizontalIconAlignmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("HorizontalTextAlignment", typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(DuoToneIcon), TextAlignment.Start, propertyChanged: OnHorizontalIconAlignmentPropertyChanged);
private static void OnHorizontalIconAlignmentPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var control = (myControl)bindable;
    control.Label.HorizontalTextAlignment = (TextAlignment)newValue;
}
```

I can use it very normally as below:

```
<local:myControl Text="Something" HorizontalIconAlignment="Center" PrimaryColor="red" />
```

The problem is, I don't want to repeat this property in the whole software, therefore I added it as style in my Style.xaml as bellow:

```
<Style TargetType="local:myControl">
    <Setter Property="PrimaryColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray900}}" />
</Style>
```

And it's working perfect, but when I change it as bellow and added HorizontalIconAlignment then I receive an Exception.

```
<Style TargetType="local:myControl">
    <Setter Property="PrimaryColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray900}}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalIconAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Did I do something wrong?

Eception:

> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position 10:37. Type
> converter failed: Exception has been thrown by the target of an
> invocation.'
>
> XmlInfo: Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you code:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HorizontalIconAlignmentProperty = 
      BindableProperty.Create("HorizontalTextAlignment", typeof(TextAlignment), typeof(DuoToneIcon), TextAlignment.Start, propertyChanged: OnHorizontalIconAlignmentPropertyChanged);
```

It should be `BindableProperty.Create("HorizontalIconAlignment"` not `HorizontalTextAlignment`. The property name in the BindableProperty.Create shoule be same as the property you delcared.

In addition, the second typeof should be the control. So it should be such as:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty HorizontalIconAlignmentProperty = 
      BindableProperty.Create("HorizontalIconAlignment", typeof(TextAlignment), 
           typeof(myControl), TextAlignment.Start, propertyChanged: OnHorizontalIconAlignmentPropertyChanged);
```

For more information, you can refert to the official document about [creating a bindable property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0#create-a-bindable-property)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Style TargetType="local:myControl">
        <Setter Property="PrimaryColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray900}}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalIconAlignment" Value="{AppThemeBinding Center}" />
    </Style>
```

I think the binding is missing you can try to add this binding as example .

Comment: It didn't work.